# SCNNode: Random color for each individial node, not all? - Swift, SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, random, colors, scenekit

If I have a function that spawns a cube right next to a previous cube whenever the user taps the screen and changes the color of the cubes as well, how can I make sure that each cube can become a random color and not the all the cubes become the same random color? I don't think I can use the same geometry for each cube because then it would inherit whatever material I originally gave to it. I want each cube that is spawned to select its own random color, not all the cubse select the same random color that it picks when tapping. I have a random color function, and it works. But if I spawn 5 cubes, and tap the screen, all 5 cubes become the same random color. But instead, I want each individual cube to be its own random color. I am using Swift, and SceneKit. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
  func randomColor2() -> UIColor{
    let red = CGFloat(drand48())
    let green = CGFloat(drand48())
    let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Right now I just say, inside of my touches began:

```
boxNodeMaterial.diffuse.contents = randomColor2
```

And I also call my createBox function which adds another box node beside the original box. I want this second box to pick it's own random color, not the same one as the original. I want this to continue for each box that is added. Box 1 can be red, green, or blue. Box 2 can be red, green, or blue, Box 3 and so forth. NOT Box 1, Box 2, Box 3 pick red for example and makes them all the same color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to create multiple `SCNGeometry`, but all of them share the same material.
This results in the problem you are describing: Changing the color of one material changes to color for all the boxes.

To avoid this, simply create a new `SCNMaterial` each time you are creating a new box.

```
//Create a new, unique material for each box
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = randomColor2()

//Copy the box (or create a new one)
let newBox = oldBox.copy()
newBox.firstMaterial = material
```